# Magento : set value from config to default attribute value

Tags: magento

on the one hand i have field called min pricecf in my module configuration
on the other hand i have an attribute called min_price that i've created unsing install script

this is the attribute :

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'min_price', array(

        'group'                       => 'Prices',
        'input'                       => 'text',
        'type'                        => 'decimal',
        'label'                       => 'Min Price',
        'backend'                     => '',
        'visible'                     => 1,
        'required'                    => 0,
        'user_defined'                => 1,
        'searchable'                  => 1,
        'filterable'                  => 0,
        'default'                     => 'Here ????',
        'comparable'                  => 1,
        'visible_on_front'            => 1,
        'visible_in_advanced_search'  => 0,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front'    => 0,
        'global'                      => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,

));
```

what i wanna do is get the value from min pricecf to min_price and that value should be the default.

Comment: have you tried to get the config value with Mage::getStoreConfig() ?

Comment: you can check the default value of min pricecf and set it to the min_price is it dynamic or static value for min pricecf?